# Scraping via PROC HTTP

Tags: sas

I wanted to use proc http to scrape quotes off Yahoo finance.  It did not produce the HTML in the `out` file, but when I used `debug level = 3` to figure what happened, the full HTML was given in the log.  What happened?  Clearly, I want the HTML in the `out` file, but the alternative of saving the log as a text will be sufficient as well.  How can I do that?

```
filename Testing "&Folder&OutFile";
%let YahooFin = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SNAP/";
proc http
    url = &YahooFin.
    out = Testing
    method = "get";
    debug level = 3;
run;
```

**EDIT**

Here are my macro variables.  Just to clarify, I did receive a HTML from my original script, but it was just the top portion, not the whole thing.  See the enclosed image.

```
%let Folder = /06specialty/Practice Scripts/;
%let OutFile = TestSNAP.txt;
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxlV.png)

Comment: Please show what the macro-variable `OutFile` resolve to. Did you try using a `.txt` file as an output?

Comment: Use `HEADEROUT=<fileref>` to capture the response headers that may indicate what unexpected happenings occurred during the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML that link generates has some really long lines (541,567 bytes).
Make sure to tell SAS to use a long enough LRECL if you are going to try to read it with a DATA step.

```
1149  proc http
1150      url = &YahooFin.
1151      out = Testing
1152      method = "get";
1153  run;

NOTE: PROCEDURE HTTP used (Total process time):
      real time           0.98 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds

NOTE: 200 OK

1154
1155  data _null_;
1156    infile testing lrecl=1000000 length=ll ;
1157    input;
1158  run;

NOTE: The infile TESTING is:

      Filename=XXXX\#LN00123,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=1000000,File Size (bytes)=777076,
      Last Modified=21Mar2021:15:23:01,
      Create Time=21Mar2021:15:20:45

NOTE: 116 records were read from the infile TESTING.
      The minimum record length was 0.
      The maximum record length was 541567.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your `OutFile` macro-variable resolve to? What is the extension of your output file?

I tried with a `.txt` file:

```
filename Testing "/path/to/want.txt";
%let YahooFin = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SNAP/";
proc http
    url = &YahooFin.
    out = Testing
    method = "get";
run;
```

And it worked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Yahoo Graph API to get quotes or historical price for a stock

```
/*Lets fetch Historic data from Microsoft*/

%let stock=MSFT;

filename test "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))\&stock..json";


proc http 
    url="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/&stock?range=1mo%str(&)interval=1d%str(&)indicators=quote%str(&)includeTimestamps=true%str(&)includeTimestamps=true%str(&)crumb=&getCrumb." 
 out=test;
 *debug level=3;
quit;


LIBNAME stock JSON "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))\&stock..json";
```

You can get more details from  https://myweirdcodes.com/stocks-fetching-historical-stock-data-with-sas